# Remove an character on bulk insert using open XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am trying to insert data in an excel by reading it onto a dataset and converting it to XML. These values have either '$' or '%' symbol in them. Since I need to calculate some values which will be used for reporting i would like to remove those special characters from them.Is it possible to do this in SQL or should i do this by looping each row in datatable .

Here is my sql code to read xml

```
declare @Xml as xml
set @Xml='<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Data>
<NetMargin>13.7%</NetMargin>
</Data>
</NewDataSet>'
declare @hDoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@Xml
select xml.NetMargin
from OPENXML(@hDoc,'/NewDataSet/Data',2)
with(
     NetMargin varchar(150) 
    )xml
exec sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Comment: Is this T-SQL? Most dialects of SQL have a string REPLACE function.

Comment: @andrew-buchan i missed that :( ..works great